Output comma separated checkbox values
I am retrieving the value of multiple checkbox options in the following format (only unique ID's are available and no way to modify the form) :
const general = document.getElementById("checkbox-tag-209");
if (general.checked) { var generalValue = document.getElementById("checkbox-tag-209").value="General"; } else { generalValue = ""; }

Then, attempting to display all the selected options with a comma separation:
const shopType = [generalValue + collisionValue + tireValue + dealershipValue];
const array = shopType.split(",");

I have tried .split(","); as well as .join(', '); but of course the results do not contain a comma.
Is there an easy way of adding a comma when multiple values are checked? I see examples of loops, but they contain a common 'name' which is not available; just unique input id's. Many thanks.

Put the values individually into the array, whichever ones are selected, and then use .join(", ") and not .split()

"Put the selected values individually into the array" Can you provide a link to an example. I thought I was doing that: [generalValue + collisionValue + tireValue + dealershipValue] Thank you for your help.

Put in an array, filter out empty strings, and join: [generalValue, collisionValue, tireValue, dealershipValue].filter(v => v).join(","). By using + you are concatenating the strings into one string, and putting that one string in an array.

It would probably be helpful for you to read up on Arrays in Javascript.

Very much appreciated, 001. Thank you!

Adding values to an internal array to keep track of what has been selected and printing those.
Added a button to display the values also outside of clicking on a checkbox; this is optional, of couse
See demo below.


// init values array
var checkedValues = [];

// get all inputs (in our HTML, only checkboxes exist)
const checkboxArray = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

// add click listeners to all checkboxes
checkboxArray.forEach(function(box) {

  // on a click get the value of the element clicked
  box.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var checkedValue = this.value;

    // determine if we are selecting it or deselecting it
    // if we are selecting it, we add it to our values array
    if (this.checked) {
      checkedValues.push(checkedValue);

    } else {
      // remove from values array - this involves filtering value out of existing array
      var filteredValues = checkedValues.filter(val => (val !== checkedValue));
      checkedValues = filteredValues;
    }

    //Then, attempting to display all the selected options with a comma separation:
    console.log(checkedValues.join(","));
  });
});

function displaySelectedValues() {
  console.log(checkedValues.join(","));
}
<input type="checkbox" value="a" /> A
<input type="checkbox" value="b" /> B
<input type="checkbox" value="c" /> C
<input type="checkbox" value="d" /> D
<input type="checkbox" value="e" /> E

<br/>
<hr/>
<button onClick="displaySelectedValues()">Display Values</button>



